# How to return the highest number that's assigned to an object value? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Here is the challenge I'm a bit stuck on:

**Create a function highestScore that takes in an array of student objects as a parameter. It should return a string that corresponds to the student with the highest score. The string should contain that student's initials concatenated with their id. Assume the array contains at least 1 student object and the student with the highest score is unique (there are no ties).**

I was able to get the correct answer, but only specifically for this challenge.  I feel my if statement is not resuable.  What is a better way to write this out?

```
function highestScore(students) {

  for(let i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
    let str = students[i].name
    let matches = str.match(/\b(\w)/g)
    let initials = matches[0].concat(matches[1])
    if(students[i].score > 95){
            return initials.concat(students[i].id)
        }
        }
}

//Uncomment the lines below to test your function:

var students = [
{name: 'Will Sentance', id: 128, score: -42},
{name: 'Jamie Bradshaw', id: 32, score: 57},
{name: 'Lisa Simpson', id: 2, score: 99},
{name: 'Luke Skywalker', id: 256, score: 94}
];

console.log(highestScore(students)); //=> 'LS2'
```

Comment: You are solving print the only student with more than 95 points. Think about a implementaion for Math.max then you can simply students.reduce((winner, student) => higherScore(winner, student), {}).toRequestedString()

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing with hardcoded value 95 use variable min initially having the lowest possible value

```
function highestScore(students) {
  let min=-100 // assuming the lowest score possible
  let studentInitials = ""
  for(let i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
    let str = students[i].name
    let matches = str.match(/\b(\w)/g)
    let initials = matches[0].concat(matches[1])
    if(students[i].score > min){
            min=students[i].score
            studentInitials = initials.concat(students[i].id)
        }
        }
    return studentInitials
}

//Uncomment the lines below to test your function:

var students = [
{name: 'Will Sentance', id: 128, score: -42},
{name: 'Jamie Bradshaw', id: 32, score: 57},
{name: 'Lisa Simpson', id: 2, score: 99},
{name: 'Luke Skywalker', id: 256, score: 94}
];

console.log(highestScore(students)); //=> 'LS2'
```

Comment: Thanks!  I have question regarding "return studentInitials".  I notice when I return studentInitials inside the if statement, if comes out with a different result.  Why is this?

Comment: It returns the first value that satisfies this condition which is not necessarily the max value

Answer (score 0):

You have to check with object contain the highest score and save that index

```js
var students = [
    { name: 'Will Sentance', id: 128, score: -42 },
    { name: 'Jamie Bradshaw', id: 32, score: 57 },
    { name: 'Lisa Simpson', id: 2, score: 99 },
    { name: 'Luke Skywalker', id: 256, score: 94 }
];


var temp = 0
var value = 0
for (const a of students) {
   
    if (value <= a.score) {
        temp++;
        value = a.score
    }  
}
console.log("The Highest Score is ::: ",students[temp]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This

```js
var students = [
{name: 'Will Sentance', id: 128, score: -42},
{name: 'Jamie Bradshaw', id: 32, score: 57},
{name: 'Lisa Simpson', id: 2, score: 99},
{name: 'Luke Skywalker', id: 256, score: 94}
];

var sortStudentBasedOnScore = function(student1, student2){
    return student1.score < student2.score
}

var getStudentCodeWithHighestScore = function($students){
    var sortedStudents = $students.sort(sortStudentBasedOnScore);
   var highestScoredStudent = sortedStudents[0];
   var [firtName, lastName] = highestScoredStudent.name.split(" ");
   return firtName[0].toUpperCase()+lastName[0].toUpperCase()+highestScoredStudent.id;
}

var code= getStudentCodeWithHighestScore(students);
console.log(code);
```

Comment: Updated the anwser, Now it's working like you want. Please remove the down vote

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `.reduce` without mutating any variable and do something like this.

```js
function highestScore(students) {
  var indexOfhighestScoreObj = students.reduce((acc, elem, index, arr)=>{
     return acc = (elem.score > arr[acc].score) ? index : acc;
  },0);
  
  return indexOfhighestScoreObj
}
var students = [
{name: 'Will Sentance', id: 128, score: -42},
{name: 'Jamie Bradshaw', id: 32, score: 57},
{name: 'Lisa Simpson', id: 2, score: 99},
{name: 'Luke Skywalker', id: 256, score: 94}
];

console.log(highestScore(students)); //=> index of highest scoring student
console.log(students[highestScore(students)]) //highest scoring student object
```